# How to use GET and POST Arguments in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, http-post, http-get

We are transforming PHP Application to Symfony2 Application.

Most of the pages we are completely writing new but some pages we decided to keep it as it is. *i.e I want to use the same php without any major change.*

In the php page we used `GET['prospect_id']`, `GET['executive_id']` and many other arguments. Both GET and Post methods. When I view the page in Symfony1.4 there is no error or warning.

But when I view in Symfony 2 I am getting `undefined index error`.

How can I solve the issue?

EDIT: if GET['prospect_id'] is null there is no error in Symfony 1.4 but i'm getting `undefined index` notice in Symfony2. There are many variables like that. Is it necessary to define variable before use it. How to avoid this notice message.

What i want is if i am using $_GET['xxx']. symfony2 should not show any notice or error. i want to escape from that.

Answer (score 1):

Use (in Symfony2) the controllers request-object, to get those params:

```php
$this->request->get('prospect_id');
$this->request->get('executive_id');
```

You can also set default values, if there is no value given. Take a look at this [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html).

Comment: cevik Thanks for the answer. but i have lot of variables like that. I have added some more text to the question.

Comment: @Arasu: Take a little time and refactor those get-params. Using `GET['var']` in a framework does not make sense IMHO. This will be just a minor fix for you. You can initialize local variables to stores those values and reuse them on another statement...

Comment: I am doing that but if there is any other options to handle this then that will be fine.